# How do you find a vector in the same direction as a given vector with a particular magnitude?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

For example: Our vector $u=8i-15j$.

I need to find a vector in the same direction as vector u, but with a magnitude of $12$. How would I do that?

Would I find my unit vector first? Then multiply by $12$??

Comment: Yes, that'll work (find unit vector, and multiply by 12)

Comment: @YujieZha Thank you! :) I thought so, but needed clarification before this evening's exam.

Comment: No problem, and good luck for the exam!

Comment: Using Pythagoras your given vector has length $17$ so multiply it by $12/17.$